# R Programming - Rstudio Error Message: Error: Found object is not a stat

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code:

```
    ggplot()+
 geom_point(aes(x = Africa_set$Africa_Predict, y = Africa_set$Africa_Real), color ="red")+
 geom_line(aes(x = Africa_set$Africa_Predict, y = predict(simplelm, newdata = Africa_set)),color="blue")+
labs(title = "Africa Population",fill="") +
  xlab("Africa_set$Africa_Predict") + 
  ylab("Africa_set$Africa_Real")
```

However, it show this error:

```
Error: Found object is not a stat
```

How can fix this?

Comment: This is off-topic here. Flagged it to be migrated to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ggplot framework requires that you specify a dataframe to use.  Your code should look more like this:

```
ggplot(Africa_set)+
 geom_point(aes(x = Africa_Predict, y = Africa_Real), color ="red")+
 geom_line(aes(x = Africa_Predict, y = predict(simplelm, newdata = Africa_set)), color="blue")+
labs(title = "Africa Population",fill="") +
  xlab("Africa_Predict") + 
  ylab("$Africa_Real")
```

Comment: I am getting the same error again. (Error: Found object is not a stat.)

Comment: @Legend You've had a number of questions put on hold/closed as off-topic. Please read the [help/on-topic] carefully, paying particular attention to the section on *Programming*. Questions about error messages when coding are almost never on topic here.